# Why does my if and elif statements only work for one button at a time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, kivy

I have my program display a list of buttons stored in a json file. I have each button's stored time, `honey`, compared to the current time, `time.time()` and the `delay` that the user inputs.

For some reason the conditional only works when there is one button. Once I add an additional button the program turns the first button green to indicate its early and the new button turns yellow to indicate that it is early. Once the new button turns red the first button turns red as well.

I have timed the program and the program runs at the correct time. Why am I having this problem and how would I fix it? Code:

```
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self): # build() returns an instance
        self.store = JsonStore("streak.json") # file that stores the streaks:
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.check_streak, 1/30.)

        return presentation

    def check_streak(self, dt):

        for child in reversed(self.root.screen_two.ids.streak_zone.children):
            honey = float(child.id)

            with open("streak.json", "r") as read_file:
                data = json.load(read_file)

            for value in data.values():
                if value['delay'] is not None:
                    delay = int(value['delay'])

                    if delay > time.time() < honey: # early (yellow)
                        child.background_normal = ''
                        child.background_color = [1, 1, 0, 1]

                    elif delay > time.time() > honey: # on time (green)
                        child.background_normal = ''
                        child.background_color = [0, 1, 0, 1]


                    elif delay < time.time() > honey: # late (red)
                        child.background_normal = ''
                        child.background_color = [1, 0, 0, 1]
```

```
def display_btn(self):
        # display the names of the streaks in a list on PageTwo
        with open("streak.json", "r") as read_file:
            data = json.load(read_file)

        for value in data.values():
            if value['delta'] is not None:
                print(f"action={value['action']}, delta={value['delta']}, grace={value['delay']}")
                streak_button = StreakButton(id=str(value['delta']), text=value['action'],
                                            on_press=self.third_screen, size=(400,50),
                                            size_hint=(None,None))
                self.root.screen_two.ids.streak_zone.add_widget(streak_button)
```

```
total = ((int(self.streak.day) * 86400) + (int(self.streak.hour) * 3600) +
                    (int(self.streak.minute) * 60)) # convert into seconds

            self.current_time = time.time()
            self.count = self.current_time + total
            grace = (int(self.streak.delay) * 60) + self.count # aka delay

            parsed = True

            # delete later just used to test
            print("[seconds:", total,']' , "[action:", self.streak.action,']',
                 "[grace:", grace,']')

            # store streak attributes inside "streak.json"
            self.store.put(self.streak.action, action=self.streak.action,
                          delay=grace, seconds=total,
                          score=0, delta=self.count)
```

streak.json file: `{"one": {"action": "one", "delay": 1557095861.2131674, "seconds": 60, "score": 0, "delta": 1557095801.2131674}, "two": {"action": "two", "delay": 1557096131.7338686, "seconds": 60, "score": 0, "delta": 1557096071.7338686}}`

Comment: Could you make a minimal example that is runnable and still produces the error. You can get some tips here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that having two loops caused my data to get mismatched. I needed to be able to either iterate over the button objects and only use the correct json file dictionary entry for each, or iterate over the json file and only modify the corresponding child. I decided to use the former.

I set up the code so that for every child in the `streak_zone` `name = child.text`

I then compare every key in my json file to the name of the button aka `child`

if the name of the key is equal to `name` then we get the value of the nested key `delay`

New code:

```
def check_streak(self, dt):

        for child in reversed(self.root.screen_two.ids.streak_zone.children):
            honey = float(child.id)
            name = child.text


            with open("streak.json", "r") as read_file:
                data = json.load(read_file)


            for key in data.keys():
                if key == name:
                    delay = data.get(key, {}).get('delay')


                if delay > time.time() < honey: # early (yellow)
                    child.background_normal = ''
                    child.background_color = [1, 1, 0, 1]

                elif delay > time.time() > honey: # on time (green)
                    child.background_normal = ''
                    child.background_color = [0, 1, 0, 1]


                elif delay < time.time() > honey: # late (red)
                    child.background_normal = ''
                    child.background_color = [1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for only one button because the `if...elif` statements are outside the `for` loop.

## Solution

Move the `if...elif` block into the `if value['delay'] is not None:` block inside the  `for` loop.

### Snippets

```
def check_streak(self, dt):

    for child in reversed(self.root.screen_two.ids.streak_zone.children):
        honey = float(child.id)

        with open("streak.json", "r") as read_file:
            data = json.load(read_file)

        for value in data.values():
            if value['delay'] is not None:
                delay = int(value['delay'])

                # fix for later
                if delay > time.time() < honey: # early (yellow)
                    child.background_normal = ''
                    child.background_color = [1, 1, 0, 1]

                elif delay > time.time() > honey: # on time (green)
                    child.background_normal = ''
                    child.background_color = [0, 1, 0, 1]

                elif delay < time.time() > honey: # late (red)
                    child.background_normal = ''
                    child.background_color = [1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Could you please share your `streak.json` file?

Comment: It doesn't work because either data is wrong or comparison is wrong or both. Recommend that you add `print()` statement to display the values of `delay`, `time.time()` and `honey`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the data and the comparison are correct. When I only have one button stored it changes colors as expected. It's only when I add a second button the first button will turn green and wait for the second button to turn red. When the second button turns red then the first button will turn red.

Comment: Could you please share your updated code for the method `check_streak()`.